# Complex Multiple Condition Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, inventory

I need to write a complex formula in excel (or if someone has a suggestion as to another program to use I'm open to it!) with multiple conditions based on where the item is stored.

Each item has a minimum and maximum par level calculated, but can be stored in multiple locations. The percentage of that par is calculated based on where that item is stored (See last image below). For example:

Item A is stored in Central location 1, Central location 2, and 2 External (aka non-central) locations. There is a total quantity of 100 Item A's.

Based on our scenarios, we would find that:

Central Location 1: 70%
Central Location 2: 20%
External Location 1:10%/# of external Locations
External Location 2:10%/# of external Locations

So our par level for that item in each location would be:
Central Location 1: 70 of Item A
Central Location 2: 20 of Item A
External Location 1: 5 of Item A
External Location 2: 5 of Item A

The left side are the storage locations for each item ID #. I need to distribute the total Min and Max to each location depending on the scenarios below
[image: pic]

I could go through and do this manually for each item (Where is stored, what is the scenario, calculate) but there are 1,500 items all stored in various places. Is there any formula I could write to calculate where the item is and how much of the item would go to each area its stored in?

I've tried using various IF and matching functions but feel like I don't have any clue where to start.

Any help would be great!

Different Scenarios of where an item can be stored. Depending on storage locations, each location will get a different percentage of the total (to the right in the image above)[image: pic]

Comment: Can't see the data structure in your spreadsheet and also how the data is used.  It will be harder to help you out.  Please post a snapshot of your data if you don't mind.

Comment: While we can assume your inventory level in column A, you will need to specify the number of central locations and the number of external locations somewhere.  Is there a maximum of 2 central locations? can you have 0 central locations.

Comment: @ForwardEd There are only 2 central locations. so it can be either Central 1, Central 2, or external. There should not be 0 central location, as any item that was only in an external location was removed or moved to central (Since we stock external from central it wouldn't make sense for us)

Comment: Please show mock data and layout with expected results.  It is hard to formulate a formula based on what you have given.  A picture helps a lot.

Comment: @ScottCraner I updated some images, It won't let me post more since I need higher reputation. I tried to upload an excel sheet but it won't let me, sorry!

Comment: @ForwardEd Ideally I would like a formula that can recognize an item has these storage locations and distribute accordingly. I'd love for it to be as automated as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the updated photo.  It changes things in my answer.  I will revamp when I come back from lunch.

Comment: Looking at your example item 11 does not have a central classification.  I asked about this scenario earlier.  is item 11 central off the example page somewhere? and where is the total quantity listed that you refer to as Q in your decision chart?

Comment: @ForwardEd Sorry about that, wrong image. 11 does have a central location, it should be updated now. The right side of the first image (Where the arrows are coming from) is the Quantity to be distributed. Sorry it's side by side - I could upload additional images/sheets to show it better. Thanks!

Comment: so if I understand correctly, from your image you want to split the Min value from your table on the right to the min value on the table on the left according to you decision model

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, that's correct. The min value from the right would be distributed to the min columns on the left based on the model. As to item 18

Comment: FYI you have two item 18s on your table on the right

Comment: @ForwardEd As to item 18, it would be treated as the third scenario from the left (Central 1 OR 2) and get 80% while external locations(closet 1 and 2) get 20% split between.

Comment: @ForwardEd Wow, I'm in rare form today, clearly need more coffee geez. Just ignore one of em, it's more about the method of being able to do it than the actual values right now :) Thank you so much, I appreciate it!

Comment: the if equation could be made easier if you are allowed to use an more helper columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## OPTION 1

[image]

Build out your reference table like above using the following formulas for columns M and N row 2 and copy down for as many items as you have

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$11=$J2)*(LEFT($A$2:$A$11)="c"))

=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$11=$J2)*(LEFT($A$2:$A$11)="e"))
```

After that in your cell M2 using the following equation and copy down:

```
=IF($A2="external",IF(INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),4)=1,0.2,0.1)*INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),2)/INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),5),IF(--RIGHT($A2)=1,IF(INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),4)=1,IF(INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),5)=0,1,0.8),0.7)*INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),2),IF(INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),5)=0,0.3,IF(INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),4)=1,0.8,0.2))))
```

in order to get your max values, repeat the concept but change

```
*INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),2)
```

to

```
*INDEX($J$2:$N$5,MATCH($C2,$J$2:$J$5,0),3)
```

The change tells it to grab the value from the 3rd column instead of the second.  There will be multiple locations to do this.

[image: POC]

## OPTION 2

Build out your table on the right to look like the following using the formula beneath the picture.

[image: POC]

Build out columns M and N as OPTION 1
Build out columns O:Q using the following:

```
=IF(AND(M3=0,N3=0),0,IF(M3=2,0.7,IF(N3=0,1,0.8))*K3)
=IF(AND(M3=0,N3=0),0,IF(M3=2,IF(N3=0,0.3,0.2),0.8)*K3)
=IF(AND(M3=0,N3=0),0,IF(M3=1,0.2,0.1)*K3/N3)
```

Repeat these fomulas in R:T changing K3 to L3

Then in column D and E use the respective formulas:

```
=INDEX($O$3:$Q$6,MATCH($C2,$J$3:$J$6,0),MATCH($A2,$O$2:$Q$2,0))
=INDEX($R$3:$T$6,MATCH($C2,$J$3:$J$6,0),MATCH($A2,$R$2:$T$2,0))
```

copy the formulas down as required.

OPTIONS 2 while more spread out is probably easier to read and thus maintain.